# Authorization required in retrofit library in android

Tags: android, android-studio, ssl, ssl-certificate, retrofit2

I am using retrofit2 library for API calls. My baseURl is in **https** i.e self signed certificate is used by me. So i used trustmanager to trust all certificate and bypass the certificate in android. Following is the code.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
      try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();


            httpClient.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager)trustAllCerts[0]);
            httpClient.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
```

And following is my call for the retrofit.

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = httpClient.build();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Utils.URL_SERVER_ADDRESS_LATEST)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
```

But after doing all of the above process I am getting following response

> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=401, message=Authorization Required, url=https://testapi.trick.net/api/login}

I hope there is any solution for this as I have been trying for past two days. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to successfully get a response from your service using a REST client?

Comment: Yes I am getting rawresponse @CoderP.

Comment: I think the username&password or a token should be sent with your request. Check your web service's requirements